# "TypeError: choice() takes exactly 2 arguments (4 given)" error

Tags: python, random, syntax-error

I'm learning new to python and I'm making a game and I had a problem in terminal of linux like you see below:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "oyun.py", line 30, in <module>
Pc=random.choice("tas","kagit","makas")
TypeError: choice() takes exactly 2 arguments (4 given)
```

Can you tell me what is the problem and what can i do?

Comment: We can't tell you what the problem is unless you show us the code that's causing an error. (Hint: It's the code around line 30 of `oyun.py`)

Comment: @RobertRouhani: there is no need for further code here - what is wrong is written on the error message (although obscured by the fact that "random.choice" is an instance method, instead of a function as it appears to be. Being a method, the implicit first parameter "self"  is passed to it at call time, making the argcount on the error message off by one.

Comment: Didn't notice that it printed that line out in the traceback... my bad :)

Answer (score 4):

You need to feed it a list. For example:

```
Pc=random.choice(["tas","kagit","makas"])
```

Answer (score 2):

If you look at the documentation, you'll see that the method random.choice takes one argument, a *seq* containing the values from which to choose. So, in this case, wrap the possible choices into a list.

One more (important) thing: Even though it looks like you provided three arguments, interpreter is complaining about four (and asking for two). That is because the object upon which the method is called (in this case "random") is the implicit first argument to the method.

HTH,
--ag